# Setting view adapter on Recycle View crashes app

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to build a minimal app for learning how to work with the recycleview and adapter and it looks like when I set the adapter, my app crashes without any logging. The code is as follows:

```
package com.example.cafe.toplevel;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.example.cafe.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TopLevelFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_COLUMN_COUNT = "column-count";
    private int mColumnCount = 1;

    public TopLevelFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static TopLevelFragment newInstance(int columnCount) {
        TopLevelFragment fragment = new TopLevelFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT, columnCount);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mColumnCount = getArguments().getInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_level, container, false);
        List<CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter.CategoryItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(new CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter.CategoryItem("1", "Drinks"));
        items.add(new CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter.CategoryItem("2", "Food"));
        CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter categoryRecyclerViewAdapter = new CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter(items);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.category_list);
        Context context = view.getContext();
        if (mColumnCount <= 1) {
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        } else {
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, mColumnCount));
        }
        recyclerView.setAdapter(categoryRecyclerViewAdapter);
        return view;
    }
}
```

any help with resolving this would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Per request, I've included the code for the adapter:

```
package com.example.cafe.toplevel;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.example.cafe.R;

import java.util.List;

public class CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    public static class CategoryItem {
        String name;
        String id;

        public CategoryItem(String id, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    private final List<CategoryItem> mValues;

    public CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter(List<CategoryItem> items) {
        mValues = items;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_level, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);
        holder.mIdView.setText(mValues.get(position).id);
        holder.mContentView.setText(mValues.get(position).name);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mValues.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final View mView;
        public final TextView mIdView;
        public final TextView mContentView;
        public CategoryItem mItem;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mView = view;
            mIdView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.category_id);
            mContentView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.category_name);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return super.toString() + " '" + mContentView.getText() + "'";
        }
    }
}
```

Add log error:

```
2021-07-07 22:36:02.916 13387-13387/com.example.cafe E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.cafe, PID: 13387
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.cafe.toplevel.CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter.java:42)
        at com.example.cafe.toplevel.CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter.java:13)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7254)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7337)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6194)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6460)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6300)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6296)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2330)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1631)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1591)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:668)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4309)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:4012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4578)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1855)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:536)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:784)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3475)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2943)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1948)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8177)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
2021-07-07 22:36:02.916 13387-13387/com.example.cafe E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7664)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: maybe something bad is happening in the adapter ,please share the adapter code

Comment: "my app crashes without any logging" - that is highly unlikely. Check the LogCat tab of Android Studio and scroll up until you find the error. https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#systemLogView

Comment: @dominicoder I see the logcat being active until I build and run the app, upon which it just blanks out

Comment: @reactor try running it from the command line. https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat Without a clear stacktrace, people are just taking blind stabs in the dark.

Comment: thank you! I running `adb logcat` got me the stacktrace and I added it to the original post.  It starts with `    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.cafe.toplevel.CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter.java:42)
    at com.example.cafe.toplevel.CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter.java:13) at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7254)`

Answer (score -1):

Your code is incorrect. You are taking the inflated layout and casting it to the RecyclerView.

```
if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
    Context context = view.getContext();
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
    if (mColumnCount <= 1) {
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    } else {
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, mColumnCount));
    }
    recyclerView.setAdapter(categoryRecyclerViewAdapter); // commenting this prevents crash but it also doesn't render the list
}
```

You should use that on the recyclerView instead. `findViewById` of the RecyclerView. Then you will be able to set adapter on that recyclerView.

Also, you are writing syntax incorrectly for the List. Don't keep empty generics for the ArrayList. It is not advisable.

```
List<CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter.CategoryItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: can you go into more detail? Usually, when answers are provided, the correct code is included. From what I'm seeing, only the code that I provided is included in the answer.

Comment: I understood your suggestion to mean to add something like this:
```
...
        RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.category_list);
        Context context = view.getContext();
        if (mColumnCount <= 1) {
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        } else {
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, mColumnCount));
        }
        recyclerView.setAdapter(categoryRecyclerViewAdapter);
      return view;
```
also, I get a lint error when trying to use a non-empty generic for a new arraylist

Comment: Ok. So does this change solve the recyclerView problem?

Comment: it does not fix it

Comment: what is the issue now? the app won't be crashing due to setting adapter. Can you please update the new code in the question?

Comment: the app is still crashing, presumably for the same reason. I've also included the adapter code per someone else's request

Comment: @reactor you are returning `view`. You should return `recyclerView`.